# Limit of a complex function (resulting in divide by zero situations)

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

I have the following limit which I'm attempting (and failing) to evaluate:

$\lim_{x \to i} (z-i)\frac{e^{imz}}{(z^2+1)^2}$

Evaluating directly, we get $\frac{0}{0}$, so can rewrite using L'Hopital's rule and get:

$\lim_{x \to i} \frac{e^{imz}(1+m+imz)}{4z(z^2+1)}$

Now, evaluating yields $\frac{e^{-m}}{0}$ which is clearly undefined.

As this limit makes up part of a larger (assignment) proof question, I'm pretty sure that there is a defined limit, but I'm not sure how to find it.

Any hints/pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

The original assignment question is:

Show that $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{cos(mx)}{(x^2+1)^2}dx=\frac{\pi e^{-m}(1+m)}{4}$ where m > 0

This is a very similar question to one that the lecturer did during a lecture, given below. So I'm trying to use the same approach. Hopefully this helps give context (perhaps I've gone wrong somewhere else).

[image: example]

Comment: $(z^2+1)$ factors as $(z+i)(z-i)$.  So the $(z-i)$ in front cancels one of the $z-i$ but there is still one more left in the denominator (because we started with $(z^2+1)^2$).  As the numerator has no singularity at $z=i$, the limit is undefined (there is a pole at $z=i$).

Comment: It is not clear to me what z is. If z=x+iy then the limit trivially exists for non-zero y. In case y=0 it indeed does not.

Comment: I've updated the question to give more context, hopefully this helps.

Comment: You have a *double* pole at $z=i$, so you need to compute the residue in another fashion.

Comment: Ohh, true. It's not simple. Didn't even occur to me. Let me give that a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a double root $a$ in the denominator, combine all the other terms into a function $f(z)$. Then your expression has the form
$$
\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^2}=\frac{f(a)+f'(a)(z-a)+(z-a)^2r(z)}{(z-a)^2}
$$
where the remainder $r(z)$ is holomorphic close to $a$. Thus the residuum results from the linear term in the numerator and is $f'(a)$.